# Cannot use a parameter in my PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables, parameters, databricks

I'm trying to simplify my databricks notebook by creating date parameters. I want my code to run with date filters, and my goal is to only have to modify one line to get my results by a period.

This is my query :

```
create or replace temp view deldet as
select 
  case when
    dyh_date_event::date between '2022-09-01' and '2022-09-31'
      then concat('2022-09-01','-','2022-09-31')
    else ('2022-10-01','-','2022-10-31')
  end as periode, 
  *
from
  hivestore.f_delivery_detail
where 
  dyh_date_event::date between '2022-09-01' and '2022-10-31';
```

This is what i tried :

```
set p1d1 = '2022-09-01';
set p1d2 = '2022-09-31';
set p2d1 = '2022-10-01';
set p2d2 = '2022-10-31';

create or replace temp view deldet as
select 
  case when
    dyh_date_event::date between p1d1 and p1d2
      then concat(p1d1,'-',p1d2)
    else (p2d1,'-',p2d2)
  end as periode, 
  *
from
  hivestore.f_delivery_detail
where 
  dyh_date_event::date between p1d1 and p2d2;
```

But it doesn't work :

AnalysisException: Column 'p1d1' does not exist

Answer (score 2):

A view can not have parameters.

You can put the query into a SQL function and then pass the parameters to the function:

```
create or replace function deldet(p1d1 date, p1d2 date, p2d1 date, p2d2 date)
as
$$
select 
  case when
    dyh_date_event::date between p1d1 and p1d2
      then concat(p1d1,'-',p1d2)
    else (p2d1,'-',p2d2)
  end as periode, 
  *
from
  hivestore.f_delivery_detail
where 
  dyh_date_event::date between p1d1 and p2d2;
$$
language sql
stable;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select *
from deldet('2022-09-01', '2022-09-30', '2022-10-01', '2022-10-31');
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! Do you have any suggest for a good documentation/book/online lesson for learning postgreSQL/SQL ? -Sorry for my bad english, it's not my first language.